# Why would a BLDC motor be "noisy" in reverse

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, configuration, vibration-motor

I have a BLDC motor on a controller I built running in both forwards and reverse.

However the reverse direction is substantially noisier than the other and the motor vibrates more almost as if the commutation sequence were wrong.

I am using the same sequence for iterating through the 6 commutation states in either direction based on the hall status.

For going forwards I take the position from the hall sensors and map that to N "state" in my list of 6 states, I then set the motors to N+1 state.

For going backwards I do the same but use the N-2 state. (modulo 6)

I am working on the assumption that N+1 is magnetic field in advance of the poles by of 60-120 degrees, N is 0-60 degrees, N-1 is -60 to 0 degrees and N-2 is -120 to -60 degrees - this seems to hold true experimentally using the N and N-1 states, the move, but slowly and jerkily.

I'm using a very low duty cycle PWM (10%) at the moment with a 32V power source (the motor is rated for 48V - this motor specifically https://en.nanotec.com/products/2873-db59c048035-a/)

Why would it consistently behave fine in one direction, but not the other?

Thanks

Comment: Is your algorithm not symmetrical somehow? Maybe you flubbed in the code somewhere. Swap any two wires between motor and controller. Does the jerkiness follow the motor's mechanical rotation or does it follow the controller's commutation direction?

Comment: Oh, it's you again. The motor braking guy.

Comment: Its definitely symmetrical - it is the exact same lookup table forward and reverse and the same hi/lo settings. 

Forwards it passes N+1 - reverse it passes N-2 (where N is in the range 0-5 and is the mapping of the hall state to the sequence of the motor)

Comment: Yeah, I don't know about that one. The only things that come to mind are: problem with the algorithm, some asymmetry with the motor, some bad positioning with the commutation hall sensors.

Comment: I'm reaching here... but the back of the motor has what looks like 2 adjustment screws holding a PCB in place inside the motor casing - you can see them on the PDF on the link to the motor. Is it plausible these are setting the position of the hall sensor and that I currently have it set biased for forwards? Unfortunately I can't find any more documentation than is on that page....

Comment: Those slotted screws? That does seem to be made to adjust something. I would assume that's to adjust hall sensor positioning. Maybe it's there for dumb controllers that can't have phase advancement dialed in. That would definitely make it rotate badly in one direction if you did not adjust the controller's phase advancement accordingly. Mechanical phase advancement would have been the first thing I would suggest if it was a brushed motor, but I ruled it out because I didn't know brushless motors had similar adjustements.

Comment: Those are the ones - and whatever the adjustment is it is not currently centred, in fact its a couple of degrees in the forwards direction.... might be worth a test...

Comment: Reduce your phase advancement in your software and see if it runs smoother in that bad direction. But if you can tell it's not centered then that's the problem right there.

Comment: Implement phase advancement then then reduce it :)

Comment: Note you should mark the existing hall board angle with a sharp tool or permanent marker, *then* adjust it. So that you can put it back precisely to the original angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screws on the back of the motor turn out to control the position of the hall sensors, it was biasaed by a few degrees in the forwards direction, adjusting them all the way to one side appears to have set them equally - it appears the motor could be biased more in the forwards direction but cannot be biased at all to reverse.

This has made the forwards directions "bumpier" which I would expect while on simple block commutation - but both side behave pretty much equally now - which gives me the starting point I was looking for.

Comment: Good. Don't forget to accept this (after 8 hours, I think) if your problem is solved.

Comment: If you compensate the timing in software based on speed instead of using the mechanical adjustment, you could have it run smoothly in both directions.

Answer (score 3):

When I was running slot cars with brushed motors in the late 60s I played with advancing the timing, by rotating the brush assembly until the forward rotation was fastest at a given voltage. This of course made the motor asymmetrical with regard to forward and reverse operation.

Your noisy reverse operation may be from a very similar situation. The motor with sensors may be "factory tuned" to operate more efficiently in the nominal forward direction.

One might try playing with the timing in the reverse direction to try to compensate for the (possibly) asymmetrical motor timing and remove the reverse direction noise. Tuning timing for minimum noise may do the trick. Hope this helps!