# BLDC motor won't start after reversing the stator axial direction

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, hall-effect, stator

I'm adapting a 60V BLDC e-scooter hub motor (see image below) to a custom made EV. In this specific motor, as it's designed for scooters, the wiring and the brake disc mounting are in opposite sides, which requires some adaptions to use it in a car.

[image: View from the 60V BLDC motor, from the brake mount side]

As a solution, i'll machine the motor wiring side to attach the brake disc, but then the tire valve will let almost no space to attach the brake callipers. So the next solution was challenging: remove the stator altogether using an hydraulic press and then putting it back reversing its direction. Now the motor won't start and a single clicking noise is heard when trying to.

Due to COVID restrictions in my country I'm not able to right now to investigate the root cause nor try new solutions in the lab. Although, two possible causes come to mind: mechanical assembly and some issue related to the hall sensors.

From my researches, when reversing the rotation direction (which I think that is the same as what i did, but instead of switching wires i've switched the stator itself, but I may be missing something here) there is no need for rearranging the hall sensors wires. I also wonder if maybe the problem is related to a [misalignment of the hall sensors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/496571/why-would-a-bldc-motor-be-noisy-in-reverse) PCB position after the reassembly.

Anyone has faced this issue before or can help to find the reason why the motor won't start? My first idea is to power the sensors and check if the signals are healthy (no 111 or 000).

I'll post updates as soon as I get to the lab to do more tests.

Comment: Last time I reversed a 3 Ph BLDC motor direction, I just swapped any 2 of 3 phase, then swapped 2 of 3 Hall sensors with 8 combinations and got it working on the last combo. Some combos just dithered back and forth.

Comment: This is an awful lot of work to use the wrong part for the job.

Comment: @BrianDrummond unfortunately the project i'm working on is low on budget and this is the available part we have here

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 thanks! i'll give it a try